# Class constructor type in typescript?

Tags: class, typescript, types, constructor

How can I declare a `class` type, so that I ensure the object is a constructor of a general class?

In the following example, I want to know which type should I give to `AnimalClass` so that it could either be `Penguin` or `Lion`:

```
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Animal");
    }
}

class Penguin extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Penguin");
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Lion");
    }
}

class Zoo {
    AnimalClass: class // AnimalClass could be 'Lion' or 'Penguin'

    constructor(AnimalClass: class) {
        this.AnimalClass = AnimalClass
        let Hector = new AnimalClass();
    }
}
```

Of course, the `class` type does not work, and it would be too general anyway.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I am not sure if this was possible in *TypeScript* when the question was originally asked, but my preferred solution is with *generics*:

```js
class Zoo<T extends Animal> {
    constructor(public readonly AnimalClass: new () => T) {
    }
}
```

This way variables `penguin` and `lion` infer concrete type `Penguin` or `Lion` even in the TypeScript intellisense.

```js
const penguinZoo = new Zoo(Penguin);
const penguin = new penguinZoo.AnimalClass(); // `penguin` is of `Penguin` type.

const lionZoo = new Zoo(Lion);
const lion = new lionZoo.AnimalClass(); // `lion` is `Lion` type.
```

Comment: +1 This answer is what the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) recommends.

Comment: You might need to specify the arguments too: `new (...args: unknown[]) => T`

Comment: @Nenad: If I change the Zoo constructor to take `(public readonly AnimalClass: new () => Lion)` or `(public readonly AnimalClass: new () => Penguin)`, it works fine and both Lion and Penguin instances are instantiated as expected. Shouldn't only the type passed to the constructor work? What gives?

Comment: @atlantis This is interesting. You can also write `const constructor: new () => Lion = Penguin;`, but not `const constructor: new () => number = Penguin;`, so it seems TS is checking return type, but somehow does not differentiate two different subclasses. Maybe a bug?

Comment: How if `AnimalClass` references `Zoo` class in it's constructor?

Comment: Does not work if you have classes with (different) constructor parameters.

Comment: @MikeLischke Having classes with different constructor parameters would make "transparent" instantiation via `Zoo.AnimalClass()` function impossible. You would have to "guess" which constructor you have to use for which type. Having classes with same constructors, but not empty, you simply change constructor definition to what you need. e.g `new (height: number) => T`. Any other approach, like `new (...args: unknown[]) => T` throws type system out of the window. And, it also defeats the purpose of type system, if you have to guess which overload of `.AnimalClass(...)` method you have to use.

Comment: Meanwhile I asked an [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841738/using-class-types-polymorphically-as-parameters-to-class-factories-without-the) about this and got a very useful answer, which works with different constructor parameter lists.

Comment: @MikeLischke Glad you've got your answer. I would only point out that your problem has nothing to do with factory pattern (any flavour of it) which you constantly keep referring too.

Comment: Someone apparently stole your answer: https://www.edureka.co/community/181339/typescript-class-constructor-type

Comment: @MartinMelichar Interesting. The website looks like some kind of Stackoverflow clone. Probably they are crawling SO for both questions and accepted answers for more popular questions.

Answer (score 89):

**Edit: This question was answered in 2016 and is kind of outdated. Look at @Nenad up-to-date answer below.**

Solution from [typescript interfaces reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
    tick();
}

function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
    return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

So the previous example becomes:

```
interface AnimalConstructor {
    new (): Animal;
}

class Animal {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Animal");
    }
}

class Penguin extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Penguin");
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Lion");
    }
}

class Zoo {
    AnimalClass: AnimalConstructor // AnimalClass can be 'Lion' or 'Penguin'
    
    constructor(AnimalClass: AnimalConstructor) {
        this.AnimalClass = AnimalClass
        let Hector = new AnimalClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that this solution did NOT work for me, and will not work if you want to use a constructor which takes a non-zero number of arguments. Took me forever to figure out why this example works but my code didn't.

The thing I found after hours of searching was to use `AnimalClass: typeof Animal`. This will work for dynamically loading subclasses of a given class.

Comment: @pixelpax You can define a non-zero argument constructor like this: `new (...args: any[]): Animal`

Comment: @Sammi, Thank you, your solution does make sense. For me, using `typeof Animal` to mean "the type of any subclass of Animal" worked really well, and looks descriptive in code.

Comment: @pixelpax Its meaningless though, as `typeof Animal` is just the string `"function"`. Any class will satisfy that, not just Animal ctors.

Comment: Not working for me. Tried: class Foo{}; var zoo = new Zoo(Foo); - no error

Comment: @OlegPolezky are you sure you tried the exact same thing? It should work. Maybe your problem is slightly different?

Comment: @arthur.sw, please check the following link. It works, but the compiler shouldn't compile the last line https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/8456/

Comment: That's right! Did you check for such issues on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues or did you create one?

Comment: `Its meaningless though, as typeof Animal is just the string "function"` -- in plain JS, yes. In TypeScript type annotation, no. `typeof X` means the type of the symbol X, whatever it is, and is being processed by the compiler statically.

Comment: And of course, no, not any class satisfy that, just the proper structural subtype. Check it yourself in a playground.

Answer (score 51):

Like that:

```
class Zoo {
    AnimalClass: typeof Animal;

    constructor(AnimalClass: typeof Animal ) {
        this.AnimalClass = AnimalClass
        let Hector = new AnimalClass();
    }
}
```

Or just:

```
class Zoo {
    constructor(public AnimalClass: typeof Animal ) {
        let Hector = new AnimalClass();
    }
}
```

`typeof Class` is the type of the class constructor. It's preferable to the custom constructor type declaration because it processes static class members properly.

Here's the relevant part of [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). Search for the `typeof`. As a part of a TypeScript type annotation, it means "give me the type of the symbol called Animal" which is the type of the class constructor function in our case.

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, you can't use the result to call `new`

Comment: `typeof Animal` is a TypeScript type annotation which "returns" the type of the Animal constructor function. It doesn't return a string.

Comment: It's always a good idea to run the code in question in typescript playground and consult the docs (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) before trying to correct the answer. Never hurts :).

Comment: Way better and more intuitive than the accepted answer!

Comment: It does not work with an abstract class though.

Comment: It does work with abstract class. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAKAUoVEhngQCsBXfABwAoBKBALgQDcA9rgAmAbjIBfMmRRoMAEUEBzBAFMAHhDXYRGHASKkKVZmy4lp0ssjWJgeQsT4QAnqzWCAZlkdGAvAhKykA

Answer (score 15):

> How can I declare a class type, so that I ensure the object is a constructor of a general class?

A Constructor type could be defined as:

```
 type AConstructorTypeOf<T> = new (...args:any[]) => T;

 class A { ... }

 function factory(Ctor: AConstructorTypeOf<A>){
   return new Ctor();
 }

const aInstance = factory(A);
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this method you lose type checking of the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)** to refer a Class Constructor

```js
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Animal");
    }
}

class Penguin extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Penguin");
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Lion");
    }
}

class Zoo {
    AnimalClass: typeof Animal // AnimalClass could be 'Lion' or 'Penguin'

    constructor(AnimalClass: typeof Animal) {
        this.AnimalClass = AnimalClass
        let Hector = new AnimalClass();
    }
}
```