# What's the best way to annotate dynamically loaded TypeScript abstract classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, abstract-class

I'm writing a library that will let you plug in external implementations, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to write types for these.

**Example**

```js
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract makeSounds();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public makeSounds() {
        console.log('woof');
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public makeSounds() {
        console.log('meow');
    }
}

type BuiltinAnimals = 'cat' | 'dog';

interface AnimalLike {
    [name: string]: new () => Animal;
}
```

```js
default class ZooClient {
    public mostFamousAnimal: Animal;
    constructor(someAnimal: BuiltinAnimals | AnimalLike) {
        if (typeof someAnimal === 'string') {
            // if 'dog', load `Dog` and if 'cat', load `Cat`.
            // this.mostFamousAnimal = new Cat() or new Dog();
        } else {
           // load external animal plugin
           // this.mostFamousAnimal = new [someAnimal]();
        }
    }

    public makeSounds() {
        this.mostFamousAnimal.makeSounds();
    }
}
```

I want to expose a few built-in classes that can be readily used, or the user can bring their own class. How do I do this?

```js
const zoo = new ZooClient('dog');
// or
const zoo = new ZooClient(new Dolphin()); // Or perhaps `new ZooClient(Dolphin)`?
```

I’m specifically looking at a neat way to be able to give nice options to users of `ZooClient` - the type information should let them know they can use a string (`BuiltinAnimal`) or a class that is their own implementation of `Animal`.

Comment: What is an instance of `ZooClient` supposed to actually do?  What do you mean by "load" `Dog`, `Cat`?

Comment: I’ve added more code to help explain my use case better.

Comment: So a `ZooClient` doesn't need to remember what type of animal it holds?  It's just `Animal`?  So if `Dog` has a `chaseCars()` method and `Cat` has a `chaseMice()` method, you don't require `new ZooClient('dog').mostFamousAnimal.chaseCars()` to compile?

Comment: Your current signature has `AnimalLike`, which is more like `{"dolphin": Dolphin}` as an argument. But yes, `new ZooClient(Dolphin)` would make more sense.

Comment: @jcalz Both `Cat` and `Dog` extend `Animal`, and I’m interested in only using the `makeSounds()`, which every implementation of `Animal` will have defined. I’m specifically looking at a neat way to be able to give nice options to users of `ZooClient` - the type information should let them know they can use a string (`BuiltinAnimal`) or a class that is their own implementation of `Animal`.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah that’s what I’m having trouble with. I’m not sure how to set it up so that ZooClient can be given a string or a new class implementation of `Animal`.

Comment: @GPX Maybe have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39614311/1048572)? For the distinction between builtin and given class, the union type and the `typeof` distinction seem totally fine to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, right now your `Cat` and `Dog` types are [structurally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) identical, meaning that the compiler can't tell the difference between them.  This isn't necessarily a problem, but it does lead to some surprising results (e.g., IntelliSense might report that a `Dog` is of type `Cat`).  For example code I usually like to [avoid such unintentionally equivalent types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible), so I'll do this:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  chaseCars() {}
  public makeSounds() {
    console.log("woof");
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  chaseMice() {}
  public makeSounds() {
    console.log("meow");
  }
}
```

Now a `Cat` and a `Dog` differ structurally (one can `chaseMice()` and the other can `chaseCars()`) as well as nominally (different names) and all is right with the world.

---

So, I'd recommend creating a keyed registry of built-in `Animal` constructors:

```
const builtInAnimals = {
  cat: Cat,
  dog: Dog
};
```

and an associated type:

```
type BuiltInAnimals = typeof builtInAnimals;
```

And then you can make your `ZooClient` class work like this:

```
class ZooClient {
  public mostFamousAnimal: Animal;
  constructor(someAnimal: keyof BuiltInAnimals | (new () => Animal)) {
    const animalConstructor =
      typeof someAnimal === "string" ? builtInAnimals[someAnimal] : someAnimal;
    this.mostFamousAnimal = new animalConstructor();
  }

  public makeSounds() {
    this.mostFamousAnimal.makeSounds();
  }
}
```

So the input to the constructor is either `keyof BuiltInAnimals` (namely `"cat"` or `"dog"` in this example) or a constructor which returns some `Animal`.  Then, the `animalConstructor` local variable uses a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) to distinguish what `someAnimal` is, and in either case is set to something of type `new() => Animal`.  We then use that constructor as you'd expect.

Let's see how it works:

```
const dogZooClient = new ZooClient("dog");
dogZooClient.makeSounds(); // woof

class Dolphin extends Animal {
  makeSounds() {
    console.log("");
  }
}
const dolphinZooClient = new ZooClient(Dolphin);
dolphinZooClient.makeSounds(); //
```

So that's the intended use, and it works.  Let's make sure it doesn't have unintended uses:

```
new ZooClient("badName"); // error!
// Argument of type '"badName"' is not assignable to
// parameter of type '"cat" | "dog" | (new () => Animal)'.

class NotAnAnimal {
  makeSmells() {
    console.log("");
  }
}
new ZooClient(NotAnAnimal); // error!
// Property 'makeSounds' is missing in type 'NotAnAnimal'
// but required in type 'Animal'.
```

Those are correctly rejected.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAKAQQAcBXEZXWBUSGeBQgawFMBlAexrYAJmAAUASgBcCAG79cwgNxkAvmTIo0GACL8A5gm4APCNxEYcBIqQpIAFmm4BhYFHETS6yrXqMOwDwCQqKStpSUsPzYYPzI3AB0yAZiAEQA7vz8AGapEiqU6uqaqOgIrogmZhZYeITE5JGOYNwAsozcYSTe1HQMTFx8ghZddpHRsfFJKan43PzpeQUIRRpRMYggNLjIEACS2Fb1GAC84UjAEDIVADR2wgYyevpqKmQQAJ5U3AgAQtu7A5HIinBCfb45BBbHb7Q51EFvLRlABaWWcDHMiEavT8A34kAAYsB8IIwMDkDJyct1qwaPB+FAxLE5uSZDwPpD-jCgfDkBgAD4IMTYbjpIWeE4APlq1mQEk82PGG2YvOcE2gdIgDIQJzGEXB82yCGZ3HJOpOZ1SrFw2H0qQQAH4oQDYeSwABtE3kgC6CBkXt5y0oEHsuDACRJhOJpLNZxFYuAqvVUE1DMky2KPj6-kGwRGCr1IbDEfxECJJJoZN5EcCQxCHgzajW6oQD30qP46NwmJ1CHjCA7XcxaTbSzIbcHGOwEBrQWGoXyCAA9EuEJkcmtSro4lRQ9gjKZzKIZfVzrn5x5zkrJolkvo0oBeDcANDsPwBQu2PCk2aYgHshdzbJ27ade37QDhz0P893yccdz3MDp1nOt8yUZdV2fN8NFAtEpwgNIQGAYQADliW4JZUKMKAoAZABCMgVywKB9BoOZgMhA0EAAclSfCiJI1IOIQMM+34RBtFwfRsFAeIwX4OjVyoNwSLMKAEDYr4fi42BLntQVUlHBBBWFUVxR1aVyQkDiEk3bQEEIkScDNbFczmZA+VGCIkAmOJbxmB9AGEdj8VibLDOxwsQ7IgBzeUXejuEomi5IQAAFKjvigT5OPPesBKE-AwzAG1DBtMF1M4iKotlDjEq2RAoG4ABHbY6uEQT93YjjyUssggA)

Comment: Fantastic! This works, and thanks for the detailed walkthrough and examples!