# How can i include constructor signatures in a class?

Tags: typescript

So I have this scenario where I perform an exclude and I am left with my expected type. When I try to instantiate a class with my type I get this error from the typescript compiler `Type 'MyClass' has no construct signatures`

```
class MyClass {
}

type U = Exclude<MyClass | string, string> // U = MyClass

// ...

function example(_myClass: U) {
    const instance = new _myClass();
    // ts error `Type 'MyClass' has no construct signatures`
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQBfDGAu8ADgKbQCq0AvNAKIAeoArgCbEA8CykMAPtBHgBOASwB2AcwA0-IWPEA%20aAHol5KnCQoIuFdAB0B3ADNGo4HmEB7UdGJ0wAW0IhiACgD6DzdwBc5AJToGNAh0MDWAtBiAmBmpNSixADu0J7eUK7%20ANzBobp4MMSCgpaC0AAGACpEpADknFq10AAWkNCilmERQozm-MLiomB4jILEEOXYQA)

Comment: Write `type U = Exclude<typeof MyClass | string, string>` and it works.

Comment: @ford04 make your comment an answer so I can select it.

Comment: @ford04 - What ioedeveloper said. But also include an explanation of what's going on (if you know). :-)

Comment: @ioedeveloper `typeof MyClass` is the static type of `MyClass` constructor function (the one which enables you to create instances from it), whereas `MyClass` would be the already instantiated type (thats why you get that error with `new`). I guess, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614311/class-constructor-type-in-typescript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392853/is-there-a-type-for-class-in-typescript-and-does-any-include-it) post already give quite good explanations. Please elaborate a bit more, if things are unclear.