# TypeScript - Getting prototype in class's static method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, static, prototype

I'm working on a multiplayer game and need to serialize and deserialize entities while sending client <-> server. To do it, I'm just sending the object as JSON, then parsing it and **assigning to an object's instance** got by registry name. In the registry I put to array string with callback to create object:

```ts
static create(registryName: string, args: {}) {
   const object = Object.assign(this.prototype,args);
   object.registryName = registryName;
   return object;
}
```

while args is my deserialized object, and the whole method is **in my abstract entity class** that all entities extend.
So what I want to get here is certain (defined in the registry) **entity instance**. However, when running the code, it throws me an **exception**, that `this.prototype` is undefined:

```
const object = Object.assign(this.prototype,args);
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
    at Array.IGameEntity.create [as x_wing]
```

And now, is there any other method that would allow me to do that? I guess current prototype does not exists because it's static method (however PhpStorm says it is valid). Of course I could just put that method in every entity class and put the class name instead of `this`, but I'm curious if the current way could work somehow.

#### Code to reproduce:

```ts
export namespace Test{
    export abstract class IGameEntity{
        registryName: string;
        readonly id: number;
        vec: {
            x: number;
            y: number;
        };
        rotation: number = 0;
        scale: number = 1;
        
        static ids = 0;

        protected constructor(vec: {x: number, y: number}, rotation: number = 0, scale: number = 1) {
            this.id = IGameEntity.ids++;
            this.vec = vec;
            this.rotation = rotation;
            this.scale = scale;
        }
        
        abstract tick(time: number);
        
        static create(registryName: string, args: {}) {
            const object = Object.assign(this.prototype,args);
            object.registryName = registryName;
            return object;
        }
    }
    
    export class XWingEntity extends IGameEntity{
        tick(time: number) {
            //something here...
        }
    }
    
    export class EntityRegistry {
        static instance: EntityRegistry;
        entities: Array<(registryName: string, data: {}) => IGameEntity> = [];

        static readonly ENTITY_X_WING: string = "x_wing";

        constructor() {
            EntityRegistry.instance = this;

            this.register();
        }

        register(){
            this.reg(EntityRegistry.ENTITY_X_WING,XWingEntity.create);
        }

        private reg(registryName: string, caller: (registryName: string, args: {}) => Object) {
            this.entities[registryName] = caller;
        }

        create(registryName: string, args: {}): IGameEntity | null {
            if(this.entities[registryName]){
                return this.entities[registryName](registryName, args);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And now sending:

```ts
    //server code
    const registry = new EntityRegistry();
    let entityServer = registry.create(EntityRegistry.ENTITY_X_WING, {x: 5, y: 3})
    //add to world, etc

    //then send
    let json = JSON.stringify(entityServer);
    //send json
    
    //client code
    //get json
    let object = JSON.parse(json);
    let entityClient = registry.create(object['registryName'],object);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of assigning to the prototype to begin with. If you're it makes a lot more sense to just send simple DTO payloads, as they are a lot easier to serialise/deserialise. And if you happen to already be serialising/deserialising into JSON, then you cannot have anything worth assigning to a prototype - it would all be plain values or arrays/objects. Even then, assigning to the prototype means you are trying to affect *all* instances. Whereas your static method seems to be a simple factory, which should just be creating instances from data.

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `create()`. If called as a method, `this` should exist, and should indeed point to the class and have a `.prototype`. Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] please?

Comment: `Object.assign(this.prototype, args)`, even if the `this` is working, is still wrong. That puts the JSON data on the prototype of all your instances! And `object === this.prototype`. What you actually want is `Object.assign(Object.create(this.prototype), args)` or (if all your entity constructors support this signature) `Object.assign(new this(), args)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*object's instance got by registry name*"? I can't see how the `create` method of an abstract `Entity` class could need a `registryName` argument. Can you show a complete code example of an entity roundtrip (instance -> json -> instance)?

Comment: @Bergi I've added code to reproduce. Also, tried `Object.create`, but still not works. To do `new this()` I need to put arguments so it also wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah, there's your problem, thanks! `this.entities[registryName](registryName, args);` does call the `create` function with the `this` keyword bound to `this.entities`. You'll want to do `this.reg(EntityRegistry.ENTITY_X_WING,XWingEntity);` and then `this.entities[registryName].create(registryName, args);`.

Comment: Amazing, it works, now, thanks!! Only one question, what type is the XWingEntity in `reg` method? I've put `any`, but curious if I can do something else. Thanks again!

Comment: It's a [class type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39614311/1048572) - `typeof IGameEntity` or maybe something like `{ create<T extends GameEntity>(this: {new(): T}, args: {}): T }`. TypeScript is a bit fiddly with subclassing there in my experience though.