# Typescript: can I use an interface as a type?

Tags: typescript, interface

This seems so simple, yet I cannot find it. What is the correct type of a set of classes that implement an interface?

```js
class A implements Interface {
  constructor(fun: any) {
    this.publish = fun
  }
  publish
  name: 'hello world'
}

class B implements Interface {
  constructor(fun: any) {
    this.publish = fun
  }
  publish
  name: 'foo bar'
}

interface Interface {
  name: string
  publish: (message: string) => void
}

function createClass(classT: any): Interface { // <-------- what is the correct type here????
  return new classT()
}

const instanceA = createClass(A)
const instanceB = createClass(B)

console.log(instanceA.name)
instanceB.publish('message')
```

I tried:
`instanceof Interface`
`typeof Interface`

I also tried:

```js
function createClass(classT: new () => Interface): Interface {
  return new classT()
}
```

receiving: `TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Interface'.   Types of construct signatures are incompatible.     Type 'new (fun: any) => B' is not assignable to type 'new () => Interface'.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class constructor type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614311/class-constructor-type-in-typescript)

Comment: `function createClass(classT: new () => Interface)`

Comment: This is not working, either. Updated post.

Comment: Well, of course these aren't compatible. the constructor of `A` now takes a parameter. Same with `B`. These don't match the parameterless constructor signature `new () => Interface`. Yet, you also don't attempt to pass a parameter when calling `new classT()`, either. Suggestion: figure out what you want to do and then ask the question. I can tell you that a signature *with* parameter typed any would be `new (x: any) => Interface` but maybe you then decide to change the code even more and it doesn't work again.

Comment: I agree with VLAZ.  The code here doesn't seem to be a [mre] since `return new classT()` is a bad thing to do when `classT` is `A` or `B`, because `A` and `B`'s constructors require an argument but you're not supplying one.  You should clear up the discrepancy for us... what are you actually trying to do?