# Using class types polymorphically as parameters to class factories without the `any` type?

Tags: typescript

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) describes how to use class types in a class factory method:

```
function create<Type>(c: { new (): Type }): Type {
  return new c();
}
```

That's a pretty common approach, but misses constructor parameters. Usually the class type is therefore extended like this:

```
function create<Type>(c: { new (...args: any[]): Type }): Type {
  return new c();
}
```

This works well, but uses the `any` keyword, which I'd like to avoid. In a concrete case I created a constructor type:

```
export type SymbolConstructor<T extends BaseSymbol> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;
```

The classes I want to create have varying constructor parameters, so I need that rest parameter.

However, that only partially works. Within the library (a node module) where I defined that everything is ok. In a class I have this method:

```
    public addNewSymbolOfType<T extends BaseSymbol>(t: SymbolConstructor<T>,
        parent: ScopedSymbol | undefined, ...args: unknown[]): T {

        const result = new t(...args);
        if (!parent || parent === this) {
            this.addSymbol(result);
        } else {
            parent.addSymbol(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and is used like this:

```
symbolTable.addNewSymbolOfType(FieldSymbol, classSymbol, `myField`);
```

where `FieldSymbol` is a class derived from `BaseSymbol` and that works nicely (in the module's unit tests).

In a project which has this node module as dependency I do the same:

```
const s = symbolTable.addNewSymbolOfType(FieldSymbol, mainSymbol, member);
```

but now I get an error saying:

> "Argument of type 'typeof FieldSymbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SymbolConstructor'.

> Types of construct signatures are incompatible.

> Type 'new (name: string, value: unknown, type?: Type | undefined) => FieldSymbol' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: unknown[]) => FieldSymbol'.

> Types of parameters 'name' and 'args' are incompatible.

> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.

When I use `any` for the constructor parameters also this case works.

What's the correct approach here if you want to use `unknown` instead of `any`?

Comment: I think you've been around this block many times, so it should be no surprise that we're going to be asking for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You are right of course, though I do not think it would make any difference if you had an example. It's more of a fundamental problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sketched out a simplified version of your API [see typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKiC2AjCAbAYQgDsBnGKAVwGMZoAeAKDjgBU5QZhiATUuAEIBDUsAw58AGmZwAglADm-Ttz5xKxANbEIAd2IBtALqMAfHAC8cYsF1wAFADpnQxaQBcctwEpL51gDcjIwAlsRcUABmQtSoaNQQKDziuHhwAN4yQjw8AHK2KfgA8pGsyMCe9OwqvPzCooV4kl5KHCBctepaOvrGpvYyLNSejURkFDR0UFXN8kqm0iwszo6uSp5zpDK%20Fv5BAL7BYRHRsYIiYlipGTKaYTyepFf4B8HUeCL8ACLA0ZR4MHiiWAyWeaRCmDAeGAmG4MH4QKSjRuQwAFiE8DwoNxPPVLhI8MZLHBjEEsjl8rpGiUyigqm0Omo8Y1Zm4Gap%20BptHpDEZ%20oM4MN0GCxuQqLQGKxWfNFksVmsPC0tixvJ52JkloKSORBejMcSbHZqE4XD4gpqYOjSI5qHqsdxHGBKKRUfZbRieN5zUtsTBKFBiLqPd7DocgA) that looks to be happy with the types. Crucially the `Args extends unknown[]` is hoisted to have its own Generic position in the signatures.

```js
export type SymbolConstructor<
  T extends BaseSymbol,
  Args extends unknown[]
> = new (...args: Args) => T;

interface ScopedSymbol {
  addNewSymbolOfType: <T extends BaseSymbol, Args extends unknown[]>(
    c: SymbolConstructor<T, Args>,
    ...args: Args
  ) => T;
}

interface BaseSymbol {
  kind: symbol;
}

class DefaultScopedSymbol implements ScopedSymbol {
  children: BaseSymbol[] = [];

  addNewSymbolOfType<T extends BaseSymbol, Args extends unknown[]>(
    c: SymbolConstructor<T, Args>,
    ...args: Args
  ): T {
    const child = new c(...args);
    this.children.push(child);
    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's great to have something in the Typescript playground included in your question to start from. Else it's not obvious how to recreate your API from scratch from the fragmented parts in your question. This would make it easier to prove and share solutions.

Comment: This cannot be modelled in the playground, because it made trouble only between different projects, not within a single project. Having said "made" indicates already you solved my problem with your answer. And not only that, you also solved another problem en passant, where the parameter list wasn't checked for validity. I could pass anything. With your change TS even tells me when parameters are not correct for the given symbol class. Great!